# ウィンドウが非アクティブでもアクティブ状態であるかのように見せたい

Tags: linux, c++, qt, qt5, x11

LinuxとQtでデスクトップアプリを開発しています。

あるウィンドウがアクティブなとき、タイトルバーに色が付きます。非アクティブになるとタイトルバーがグレーになります。

**アクティブ**
[image: アクティブ]

**非アクティブ**
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

一般的なアプリとしては当たり前な挙動なのですが、このウィンドウが非アクティブになったときでも、タイトルバーの色を変えずに、アクティブ状態であるかのような見た目で描画させたいです。

アプリの動作的に、非アクティブになってもアクティブにしたい、のような無茶な要求ではなくて、あくまでも、アクティブウィンドウであるかのように、タイトルバーを描画したいだけで、見た目の問題です。

このようなことは可能でしょうか？

p.s. 余談ですが、WindowsではWM_NCACTIVATEの処理に細工することで同じようなことができました。

Answer (score 1):

クロスプラットフォームな形でQtからタイトルバーの色を指定することはできないようです．（Windowsだけならsoramimiさんのおっしゃるように抜け道があるようですが）

対処としてウィンドウのタイトルバーとボーダーを除去してあたかもタイトルバーのようなものを自分で描画するというやり方が考えられますが，その場合はウィンドウのムーブやリサイズの処理も自分で書く必要があります．

参考
http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/4778-Title-Bar-Color
http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/8596-Color-of-Titlebar-and-Menubar
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28481109/how-to-change-color-of-qmainwindow-borders-and-title-bar

Comment: フレームやタイトルバーの描画は、Qtよりもウィンドウマネージャーの仕事だと思うので、ウィンドウマネージャーに対して、「自分はアクティブである」と偽装する手段がないかな、と思いました。フレームの描画やムーブやリサイズなどを自前で実装するのはさすがに避けたいですね。